# created block for image is not displaying

Tags: blocks

I created the block for a image where in I want to display in all pages, but after creating the blocks once I see the page the created block is not displaying.

Following method  followed to create a block.

1] Structure->Blocks->Add Block

2]specified the name and browsed the picture( i have installed IMCE)

3] and chosen to display in bottom fist and also in all pages then save the 
block.

But couldn't see the block in all pages, if any one know please help me.

Comment: Check if the `img` tag is allowed for the input type of that block. Most likely the image is being stripped out if you selected `Filtered HTML` without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

when you create block then you have options for visibility where you want to show this block like below:

[image]